# How to assign static ip address to a set of machines connected to the same router via LAN cable?

Tags: networking, ip, router, static-ip-address

I have 3 machines, connected to the same router via LAN cables, router is connected to WAN for internet.
I want to assign static ip address to each machines so that they are reachable over SSH also ping each other with the assigned ip address .
The machines are running on Ubuntu 18.04

So I trying to assign static ip address to one of the machines.
I have configured my nelplan yaml file as follows:

```
network:     
  version: 2     
  renderer: networkd     
  ethernets:  
     eno1:  
      dhcp4: no    
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]   
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1  
      nameservers:  
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

The ip is being assigned to the machine but the internet stops working the second I apply the changes.
What am I doing wrong here?
Please help !!
This is making me crazy.

Comment: are you sure the default gateways ip is correct? Looks fine to me..

Comment: I don't know anything about networking, how can I verify my default gateway ?

Comment: The default gateway is where every ip package is sent, except for these targeting the local network. In your case, your router should be your default gateway, so verify that your router has the ip 192.168.1.1 and that you can ping it from your machine. The default gateway is what you specify with gateway4.

Comment: Okay I will try and verify.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I did not configure the gateway ip address properly, it should be same as the static ip address assigned by the ISP to the router.
Its rectified now !